# extension of linear maps between Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces, then any map $T:X\rightarrow Y^*$ admits a unique weak* to weak* continuous extension $\tilde{T}:X^{**} \rightarrow Y^{*}$ such that $\|\tilde{T}\|=\|T\|$.

I want to take $\tilde{T}=(T^*|Y)^*$, which is a map from$X^{**}$ to $Y^{**}$, but how to show it is a unique weak* to weak* continuous extension such that $\|\tilde{T}\|=\|T\|$.

Comment: Are you sure that $T$ goes from $X$ to $Y^*$, not $Y$? The way you define $\tilde{T}$, it is a map $X^{**}\rightarrow Y^*$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will denote by $i_X$ etc. the  canonical inclusions into bidual $X\rightarrow X^{**}$.

Let $p\colon Y^{***}\rightarrow Y^*$ be defined as the transpose of $i_{Y}$.

Define $\tilde{T}=p\circ T^{**}\colon X^{**}\rightarrow Y^{***}\rightarrow Y^*$. It is weak$^*$-weak$^*$ continuous because p and $T^{**}$ are weak$^*$-weak$^*$ continuous. Next, for $x\in X,y\in Y$ we have
$$
\langle\tilde{T}(i_X(x)),y\rangle=\langle T^{**}(i_X(x)),i_Y(y)\rangle=\langle i_X(x),T^*(i_Y(y))\rangle=\langle T^*(i_Y(y)),x\rangle= \langle Tx,y\rangle
$$
which proves $\tilde{T}\circ i_X=id$.

Uniqueness of $\tilde{T}$ follows from the Goldstine theorem.

Comment: Is the canonical inclusion defined as following : $i(x)=\hat{x}$, where $x\in X, \hat{x}(x^*)=x^*(x)$.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely this map.